# How can i make embad with slashcommand?

Tags: discord.py

I can't come up with any ideas.... (and How can i write interaction and ctx together?)

```
@bot.tree.command(name="유저2")
async def information2(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    embed = discord.Embed(title="title", description='description', color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I tried running this code, but there was an error.

(error message)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\suver_V1.py", line 300, in 
@bot.tree.command(name="유저2")
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\tree.py", line 887, in decorator
command = Command(
^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 666, in **init**
self._params: Dict[str, CommandParameter] = _extract_parameters_from_callback(callback, callback.**globals**)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\discord\app_commands\commands.py", line 371, in _extract_parameters_from_callback
raise TypeError(f'parameter {parameter.name!r} is missing a type annotation in callback {func.**qualname**!r}')
TypeError: parameter 'ctx' is missing a type annotation in callback 'information2'
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads> python suver_V1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\suver_V1.py", line 301, in 
async def information2(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
How can i do?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
async def information2(ctx: interaction:discord.Interaction):
```

edit: i found the problem. you're using embed=embed, and you can't have that. what i reccomend doing is

```
@bot.tree.command(name="유저2")
async def information2(ctx: interactions.CommandContext):
    em = discord.Embed(title="title", description='description', color=discord.Color.green())
    await ctx.send(em=embed)
```